# Ajax update after Delete action on Index view in ASP.MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to do an Ajax delete in a fairly standard Index view, i.e. I have a generated Index view with one added filter drop-down, of little relevance here.  I have changed the free Delete Html.ActionLink on every row to an Ajax.ActionLink, and the delete and ajax update work, but whichever container div I try and update, I always somehow get some kind of nesting in the updated page, e.g. after a delete and update, I get duplicate Home and About links from the master page inside my content.

Here is my current action link that causes what I describe above:

```
<%: Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.InstallationDBNumber }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "jobList" }) %>
```

... and here is where `jobList` is located, just outside the table used for the index list:

```
    <div style="clear: both;">
    </div>
    <div id="jobList" class="index-list">
        <table>
            <tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post your code for your Delete action method on your controller.  But from the sounds of it, you are returning `Return View(myModel)` instead of `Return PartialView("partialViewName", myModel)`.

Create a partial view contianing the layout information for jobList and return that from your controller action method.